N-functions (Young functions)
I'm trying to prove an integral inequality of N-functions. Let $F$ be a $\Delta_2$ N-function and denote $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau) d\tau$.
Recall that function $F:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is called a Young function if
it is continuous, convex and satisfies conditions $F(0) = 0$, $F(t)>0$ for $t>0$,
$$
 \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(t)}{t} =0 \quad \text{and}\quad \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{F(t)}{t} =\infty.
 $$
A Young function $F$ is said to satisfy $\Delta_2$-condition if there exist constants $k>1$ and $t_1 > 0$ such that
$$
  F(2t) \leqslant k F(t) \quad \text{for} ~ t \geqslant t_1.
  $$
Given $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a smooth bounded domain and $u_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^F (\Omega)$, I'm trying to prove that
\begin{equation}
0 \leqslant \int_\Omega f(u_n)u_n dx \leqslant C \int_\Omega F(u_n) dx.
\end{equation}
I known that by the $\Delta_2$ condition, it holds that for $t \geqslant t_1$,
$$
k F(t) \geqslant F(2t)= \int_{0}^{2t} f(x) dx \geqslant \int_{t}^{2t} f(x) dx \geqslant tf(t).
$$
But I don't know how to prove the rest. Can someone please help?

If you set $t:= u_n(x)$ in your last inequality and integrate $\int_\Omega  \dots dx$ then you get the desired inequality. Do I miss something?

Yes, you should notice that the last inequality holds for $t \geqslant t_1$, but the size of $|u_n (x)|$ is unknown.
